# Equivalent definitions of isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, inner-products, vector-space-isomorphism

Consider a map $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\lVert T(x)\rVert=\lVert x\rVert$.

Is this equivalent to stating that $\langle x, y\rangle=\langle T(x), T(y)\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the usual inner product?

Comment: Please, specify if T is assumed to be linear or not. Answer to your question depends on this.

Answer (score 3):

YES it is equivalent.

1. If $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle Tx,Ty\rangle$, for $x=y$:
   $$\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\|Tx\|^2,$$
   and hence $\|x\|=\|Tx\|,$ for all $x$.
2. If $\|x\|=\|Tx\|,$ then $\|x\|^2=\|Tx\|^2,$ for all $x$. Replace $x$ by $x+y$ and obtain:
   $$
   \langle x,x\rangle+2\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=\|x+y\|^2=\|Tx+Ty\|^2=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle+2\langle Tx,Ty\rangle+\langle Ty,Ty\rangle,
   $$
   and since $\langle x,x\rangle=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle$
   and $\langle y,y\rangle=\langle Ty,Ty\rangle$, then
   $$
   \langle x,y\rangle=\langle Tx,Ty\rangle,
   $$
   for all $x,y$.

Comment: This is equivalent for linear maps, of course. If you drop linearity, this does not work any more; that is, preservation of the norm does not imply preservation, of the scalar product. For example consider the map $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by $T(x)=(\Vert x\Vert, 0)$.